# How to get the key of the current item of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

When navigating through array with `next()` and `prev()`, how could you get the current key the array is at?

Comment: you found `next()` and `prev()` but you didnt find `key()`? Oo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`key` function](https://www.php.net/key) :

> key() returns the index element of the
> current array position.

And, as a quick example, you can consider this portion of code :

```
$array = array(
    'first' => 123,
    'second' => 456,
    'last' => 789, 
);

reset($array);      // Place pointer on the first element
next($array);       // Advance to the second one
$key = key($array); // Get the key of the current (i.e. second) element

var_dump($key);
```

It'll output, as expected, the key of the second element :

```
string 'second' (length=6)
```

Comment: How dare you beat me by 3 seconds? +1

Comment: Well, I suppose I don't have the ability to travel back in time... But I suppose I pressed F5 a couple of seconds before you did ^^

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`key` function](http://php.net/key) to get the key of the item the internal pointer is currently pointing to.

Comment: How dare you beat me by 47 seconds? +1

Comment: @BillyONeal: Moderators can travel back in time. ;-)

Comment: Well whoever was first should get the best answer. You're all right, obviously.

Comment: Agreed Brian Lacy. Just was trying to make a joke... failed miserably at that apparently.

Comment: @BillONeal: Fear not, I caught the jest, really was just commenting on the fact that three people gave the same correct answer in a matter of like two minutes. Of course it helps that the question was a simple one!

Answer (score 5):

You probably want [key()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php).

Answer (score 1):

you can get this in very simple way that is

```
foreach( $array as $key=>$value)
{   
   echo " Key ". $key;
}
```

It will echo  last key name .. you can manage after that  as you want to do. \
My solution is for  get current key name of Array Index.